# How can I download the most recent version of a GitHub project to use in a bash script?

Tags: bash, github

I'm working on a script that sets up a CMS ([Statamic](http://statamic.com)) so that devs can jump right into writing code and not have to manually move stuff around, gather commonly used code from GitHub, and so on.

I need a way to grab the most recent version of a project from GitHub, unzip it, and be able to move stuff around without knowing the lastest sha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code

```
# Download most recent version from GitHub
curl -L -o DOWNLOADED_FILE_NAME.zip https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO/zipball/BRANCH
unzip DOWNLOADED_FILE_NAME.zip
# Find out the name of the unzipped dir and assign it to a variable.
UNZIPPED_DIR=$(compgen -A builtin -f USER-REPO)
rm DOWNLOADED_FILE_NAME.zip
```

### Explanation

- `-L` tells curl to follow the redirect.
- `-o` specifies the name of the downloaded file.
- Read this for [info](https://help.github.com/articles/downloading-files-from-the-command-line) on downloading GitHub files from the command line.
- For info on compgen, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511683/bash-get-list-of-commands-starting-with-a-given-string/511787#511787) to another question.